How to Load Image in Kotlin Compose WASM from the Internet?
Hey everyone,
I'm currently exploring Kotlin Compose for WebAssembly (WASM) and I'm trying to figure out how to load images from the internet within my Compose application. I've been searching through the documentation and various resources, but I haven't found a clear solution yet.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
I want to dynamically load images from URLs and display them within my Kotlin Compose WASM application.
I've tried using the Image component in Compose, but it seems to only support local resources or resources bundled within the application. Is there a way to fetch and display images from URLs directly?
My specific questions are:

Is it currently possible to load images from the internet in Kotlin Compose WASM?
If so, what are the recommended approaches or libraries to achieve this?
Are there any examples or tutorials available that demonstrate how to implement this functionality?

Any help or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

I think Coil should not only work for Android, it also has Kotlin Multiplatform support and therefore should probably also work for projects targeting WASM. It has at least some experimental support. But since Kotlin targeting WASM is alpha anyways, that's probably the best you can hope for.
